# jQuery transfer effect & callback function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to know if the jQuery transfer effect has any callback mechanism by which I can determine when a transfer effect starts and when ends. I got the code below, but I found no callback function…

Please help. Thanks.

```
$("div").click(function () {
  var i = 1 - $("div").index(this);
  $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $("div").eq(i) }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about jQuery UI's [`effect`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/) method, then it takes a [`callback`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#option-callback) function as an argument. That callback will run when the effect has completed:

```
$(this).effect("transfer", { to: $("div").eq(i) }, 1000, function() {
    //Done!
});
```

As for when the effect starts, the lines following the call to `effect` should be run immediately after the call (so before the effect is complete).

Comment: is there any way to determine before the effect start and effect end. there is one callback option so then how it will be possible to determine that effect star & end through one callback...if user want to do something before effect start & after effect end then how to write the code...please advise thanks.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the callback runs when the effect ends. There is no way to provide a function that runs before the effect, but you can just call one before the call to `effect`. Or after for that matter - execution will continue as the effect occurs.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the ["Transfer effect"](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Transfer) does not state so, but the documentation for [`effect`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/effect) does state that a callback can be specified. Obviously this is the completion callback.

```
effect( effect, [options], [speed], [callback] )
```

As for when it starts, you must assume that is "immediately".

Comment: is there any way to determine before the effect start and effect end. there is one callback option so then how it will be possible to determine that effect star & end through one callback...if user want to do something before effect start & after effect end then how to write the code...please advise thanks.